# Sort std::unordered_map<std::string, std::atomic<unsigned int>> by values

Tags: c++, c++17

I've got `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::atomic<unsigned int>>`.

I would like to print the keys and values, sorted by the values.
The best solution I've encountered is to create a vector of pairs and sort that

But as one cannot copy `std::atomic<unsigned int>`, what is the most efficient solution?

Comment: You could use `std::map` with a custom comparator that sorts on the value instead of the key.

Comment: To my understanding a custom comparator works on the keys anyway, not on the values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This sounds like a very weird idea.

Comment: You want to sort on the value of an atomic, can you guarantee that no other thread is changing them while sorting?

Comment: @JVApen yes, this is done when all theads are finished. I don't mind even copying everything to a `map<string, unsigned int>` and sort that, but that sounds inefficient.

Comment: I would recommend `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned int>>>` and sort it. Or even `std::vector<std::pair<std::string_view, unsigned int>>>`  when available.

Comment: The comparator gets the key. From the key you can get the value. It not optimal, and "weird" as @BaummitAugen calls it. You might want to consider other solutions, like perhaps using [Boost bimap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) or vectors. Or better yet try to explain what the *actual* problem you want to solve is. *Why* do you want to use such a solution to an (for us) unknown problem? Perhaps we can help you find better solutions if we know the actual problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making a copy of your data into a vector will work, but you would need to provide a custom operation that calls `load()` on your `atomic<unsigned>`  to make it a plain `unsigned`. Since you are forced to do it anyway, you might as well reverse the order of terms in the pair:

```
std::vector<pair<unsigned int,std::string>> copy;
std::transform(
    m.begin()
,   m.end()
,   back_inserter(copy)
,   [](const pair<const std::string, std::atomic<unsigned int>>& p) {
        return make_pair(p.second.load(), p.first);
    }
);
```

Now that the value is first, the call of `std::sort` no longer requires a custom comparator:

```
std::sort(copy.begin(), copy.end());
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/zMPYPr)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to copy `unordered_map` into `multimap` with values being the keys and then print it out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <atomic>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::atomic<unsigned int>> m;
    for (auto p : std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, unsigned int>>{{ "a", 32},{ "b" , 22 },{ "c" , 32 },{ "d" , 22 },{ "e" , 55 } })
        m.emplace(p);

    std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string> printmap;

    std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::inserter(printmap, printmap.end()),
        [](auto const &p) { return std::make_pair(p.second.load(), p.first); });

    for (auto const &p : printmap)
        std::cout << p.first << " - " << p.second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/MgtMY8

```
22 - d
22 - b
32 - c
32 - a
55 - e
```